# FXML/JavaFX How to make an ImageView Clickable?

Tags: javafx, fxml

I want to change the Image in the Image View using FXML and to change the Image I open the fileChooser to pick an image that should replace the old one , I have 2 issues right now :

How to make the ImageView Clickable this is the code I'm using for this

```
public void imagePicker(){

    Defaultview.setPickOnBounds(true); // allows click on transparent areas
    Defaultview.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
        fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage());
    });
}
```

in my FXML file I have:

```xml
<ImageView fx:id="Defaultview" fitHeight="93" fitWidth="93"
    pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" onAction='#imagePicker'>
```

and for the image change I'd like to change it from

`Image url="@../images/default.png"`

to the Image Chosen .

Comment: Why did you just delete the FXML??? And why did you delete my formatting corrections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ImageView` doesn't have an `onAction` property (so I think you should get a runtime error when you load your FXML file). If you want to respond to mouse clicks, then you should use `onMouseClicked`:

```xml
<ImageView fx:id="Defaultview" fitHeight="93" fitWidth="93" 
    pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" onMouseClicked='#imagePicker'>
```

Registering the event handler in FXML means that the `imagePicker()` method will be invoked when the event occurs (i.e. when the user clicks on the image view). There is no need (and it's incorrect) to set the `onClicked` handler from inside the method that is invoked when the `onClick` event occurs. All you need is

```
public void imagePicker(){
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
    // use existing window here, don't create a new one:
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(Defaultview.getScene().getWindow());
    if (file != null) {
        Defaultview.setImage(new Image(file.toURI().toString()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In JavaFx ImageView has **setOnMouseClicked** property,so if you want to import an image from your PC using fileChooser ,you need to **add an extension** to your FileChooser to define only images and skip other files

```
 public void imagePicker(){
     FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
     FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterJPG = new  FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPG files (*.jpg)", "*.JPG");
     FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterPNG = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PNG files (*.png)", "*.PNG");
     fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(extFilterJPG, extFilterPNG);

    File ChooserFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(Defaultview.getScene().getWindow());//your owner
    if (ChooserFile != null) {

        Image image = new Image(ChooserFile.toURI().toString());

        Defaultview.setImage(image);
    }


  }
```

and add  MouseEvent (setOnMouseClicked) to your ImageView :

```
      Defaultview.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            imagePicker();
        }
    });
```